# Concatenate All Properties to a String with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Line;
    public string Name1;
    public string Name2;
}
```

and a collection of MyClass objects:

```
List<MyClass> myObjs = myService.GetObjects();
```

where `myObjs` has 2 elements:

```
[0]: Line: 1, Name1: "Test1", Name2: "Test2"
[1]: Line: 2, Name1: "Test3", Name2: "Test4"
```

I'd like to get every object with their properties concatenated in a string like:

```
"1,Test1,Test2;2,Test3,Test4"
```

I tried `string.Join(",", myObjs.Select(x => x.Line));`

but that only gives me a list of all the Line values. I need everything in the object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it's OK to list fields manually:

```
String.Join(";", myObjs.Select(x => $"{x.Line},{x.Name1},{x.Name2}"))
```

If not, but all fields are non-collections, generics or indexers

```
var fields = typeof(MyClass).GetFields();
var result = String.Join(";", myObjs.Select(x => 
                 String.Join(",", fields.Select(f => f.GetValue(x)))
             ));
```

NOTE: If your class actually have properties instead of fields, you should use `GetProperties()` instead of `GetFields()`.

---

And last option, if it's OK to override `ToString()` method of your class:

```
 public override string ToString() => $"{Line},{Name1},{Name2}";
```

And converting list of such objects will look like

```
 String.Join(";", myObjs)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get your object's fields separated by commas:

```
myObjs.Select( x =>
              String.Join( ",", new [] { x.Line.ToString(), x.Name1, x.Name2 } ));
```

Here is the full answer which will separate each object with semi-colons and use the above code:

```
var result = string.Join(";", myObjs.Select( x =>
                  String.Join( ",", new [] { x.Line.ToString(), x.Name1, x.Name2 } )
             ));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the more generic way for list if anyone needs,

```
    private string GetConcatedString<T>(List<T> listItems, char delimiter) 
    {  
        var fields = Type.GetType(listItems.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].FullName).GetProperties();
        return string.Join("", listItems.Select(x =>
                         string.Join(delimiter, fields.Select(f => f.GetValue(x))).TrimEnd(delimiter)));
    }
```